# How to specify DataSource in JdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot

In my application.properties I have set:

```
datasource.test.driverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource.test.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/test
datasource.test.username=admin
datasource.test.password=admin

logging.level.com.eternity = DEBUG
```

In my controller, I am trying to execute some SQL query form a string like this:

```
String selectQueryPartOne = "SELECT name, ("+ StringUtils.join(sumString, " + ")+") AS 'Price' FROM house WHERE NOT (" +StringUtils.join(sumString, " IS NULL OR ")+" IS NULL);";
JdbcTemplate statement = new JdbcTemplate();
statement.queryForList(selectQueryPartOne);
```

Which would work fine, however, I am receiving the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified
```

I've discovered, that in my `statement` object, I need to setDataSource first. However, I have no idea where I can get this dataSource object. Could you help?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot (according to your tags) that already creates ` JdbcTemplate` for you, why are you creating one yourself? Just inject it.

Comment: Yes, as @M.Deinum says, if you create it yourself you are not using the one created by Spring, and therefore do not get the DataSource injected. Just autowire the JdbcTemplate and use that one instead.

Comment: How can I inject it? I have just begun expolring Spring, so I am really sorry if that is a stupid question

Comment: Better to add `@Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate` as a private instance field. This does assume that your Controller is properly annotated with `@Controller` as well.

Comment: Also, the Spring and Spring Boot documentation are very good - I would recommend going through them and their tutorials if you are starting out.

Comment: Thanks! I it works great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create the `JdbcTemplate` instance yourself, you are working outside of the Spring dependency injection, and therefore will not have the `DataSource` injected. You need to use the Spring-provided instance via autowiring, something like:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String myAction(){
        // do stuff with the jdbc template
    }
}
```

Also, the Spring and Spring-boot documentation are great resources for further study on working with spring.